# Is it possible to find key in multi level structure with _.where()?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have different kind of objects, and I don't really want to expose each key by key, but that's the only way to make `_.where()` work.

**Is there a way to search multi level structure?**

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wRxku/)

**Here is object tree:**

```
{
    type: 1
},
{
    config: {
        type: 2
    }
},
{
    name: "super"
}
```

**Here is what I want to achieve:**

```
_.where(objectList,{config: {type: 2}})
```

return
`[{
    config: {
        type: 2
    }
}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best solution for complex Objects, but using `filter` works for your above example:

```
_.filter(objectList, function(v){ 
    return _.isObject(v.config) && v.config.type == 2; 
});
```